# Convert string to number and add one

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

I want to turn the value I get from the id into a number and add one to it then pass the new value into the `dosomething()` function to use. When I tried this and the value is one I get back 11 not 2.

```
$('.load_more').live("click",function() { // When user clicks
    var newcurrentpageTemp = $(this).attr("id") + 1;// Get id from the hyperlink
    alert(parseInt(newcurrentpageTemp));
    dosomething();
});
```

Answer (score 191, accepted):

Assuming you are correct and your id is a proper number (without any other text), you should parse the id and then add one to it:

```
var currentPage = parseInt($(this).attr('id'), 10);
++currentPage;

doSomething(currentPage);
```

Comment: @Justin Niessner, You could also just do a `+ 1` on the end of the first line rather than using a `++` pre-incrementer on a second line to be more compact.

Comment: @Chris - You could but I wanted the example to be clear which operation was happening first.

Comment: @Justin Niessner, fair enough. Brackets can help clarify the order of execution too. +1 for a clear quick answer though. Just bet me to it.

Comment: @Niklas, See my answer for the bracketed one line option.

Answer (score 11):

Have you tried flip-flopping it a bit?

```
var newcurrentpageTemp = parseInt($(this).attr("id"));
newcurrentpageTemp++;
alert(newcurrentpageTemp));
```

Comment: sort it now was not a number had <div in it however I now get 11 not 2 when the value is 1. so it is not added 1 + 1 = 2

Answer (score 8):

I believe you should add 1 *after* passing it to parseInt

```
$('.load_more').live("click",function() { //When user clicks
          var newcurrentpageTemp = parseInt($(this).attr("id")) + 1;   
          alert(newcurrentpageTemp);
          dosomething();
      });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GfqMM/

Answer (score 7):

```
$('.load_more').live("click",function() { //When user clicks
          var newcurrentpageTemp = parseInt($(this).attr("id")) + 1
          dosomething(newcurrentpageTemp );
      });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GfqMM/

Answer (score 5):

Parse the Id as it would be string and then add.

e.g.

```
$('.load_more').live("click",function() { //When user clicks
    var newcurrentpageTemp = parseInt($(this).attr("id")) + 1;//Get the id from the hyperlink
    alert(newcurrentpageTemp);
    dosomething();
});
```

Answer (score 5):

I've got this working in a similar situation for moving to next page like this:

```
$("#page_next").click(function () {
    $("#pageNumber").val(parseInt($("#pageNumber").val()) + 1);
    submitForm(this);
    return false;
});
```

You should be able to add brackets to achieve what you want something like this:

```
var newcurrentpageTemp = (parseInt($(this).attr("id"))) + 1;//Get the id from the hyperlink
```

Answer (score 5):

You have to parse the id before adding 1

```
 $('.load_more').live("click",function() { //When user clicks
              var newcurrentpageTemp = parseInt($(this).attr("id"));
              newcurrentpageTemp ++;
              dosomething(newcurrentpageTemp );
 });
```

Answer (score 4):

The simplest solution here is to change

```
  var newcurrentpageTemp = $(this).attr("id") + 1;//Get the id from the hyperlink
```

to:

```
  var newcurrentpageTemp = (($(this).attr("id")) * 1) + 1;//Get the id from the hyperlink
```

Comment: Right you are -- that IS the simplest, and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

The parseInt solution is the best way to go as it is clear what is happening.

For completeness it is worth mentioning that this can also be done with the + operator

```
$('.load_more').live("click",function() { //When user clicks
  var newcurrentpageTemp = +$(this).attr("id") + 1; //Get the id from the hyperlink
  alert(newcurrentpageTemp);
  dosomething();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

a nice way from http://try.jquery.com/levels/4/challenges/16  :

adding a **+** before the string without using parseInt and parseFloat and radix and errors i faced for missing radix parameter

sample

```
var number= +$('#inputForm').val();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var sVal = '234';
var iNum = parseInt(sVal); //Output will be 234.
```

http://www.jquerybyexample.net/2013/02/jquery-convert-string-to-integer.html

Answer (score 0):

```
var first_value = '2';
// convert this string value into int
parseInt(first_value);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple and best solution is like this. take a string in one variable and then convert it using parseInt() method like below.

```
var stringValue = '921795';
var numValue = parseInt(stringValue);
```

parseInt() method will return the number like this 921795. after this, you can add any number to your value.

http://www.phpcodify.com/convert-string-to-integer-using-jquery-parseint/

Comment: This answer has already been given multuiple times. How is this answer different/better?